# How do you convert an html div to image and then save as gif or png?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried figuring out a multitude of coded div to image methods on stackoverflow and across the internet. The codes aren't working for me, because none of methods are exactly what I need and I'm screwing up the code with my modifications to fit what I need.

Anyway, a few minutes ago I found someone who is actually applying the code to divs that are set up like mine. Please take a look at his/her tool (it's what I am doing just with a few more images):

http://kpomservices.com/html5canvas/indexsucc.html

and his/her blueprint (source file):

view-source:http://kpomservices.com/html5canvas/indexsucc.html

This is what I did:

1. I copied the scripts from the source file (found after `</body>` tag):

   `<script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
      <script src="js/base64.js"></script>
      <script src="js/canvas2image.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>`
2. I pasted it into my header file above the `</head>`.
3. I replaced all `src=""` with complete urls (they aren't hosted on my servers yet, because I'm testing to see if this will even work for me first).
4. I copied the function script from http://kpomservices.com/HTML_to_Canvas.php:

   ```
   function convert() {
                   dom = document.getElementById('watch');

                   // execute the html2canvas script
                   var script,
                   $this = this,
                   options = this.options,
                   runH2c = function(){
                       try {
                           var canvas =     window.html2canvas([ document.getElementById('watch') ], {
                               onrendered: function( canvas ) {

                               /*
                               canvas is the actual canvas element,
                               to append it to the page call for example
                               */
                               window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
                               //document.body.appendChild( canvas );
                               }
                           });
                       } catch( e ) {
                           $this.h2cDone = true;
                           log("Error in html2canvas: " + e.message);
                       }
                   };

                   if ( window.html2canvas === undefined && script === undefined ) {
                   } else {.
                       // html2canvas already loaded, just run it then
                       runH2c();
                   }
               }
   ```
5. I pasted it, as is, between `<script></script>` tags in the header file.
6. I replaced both (2) instances `document.getElementById('watch')` with my div id name:
   `document.getElementById('captme')`.
7. I copied and pasted the displaybox styling from the source file and pasted it before the `</head>` in header file (I also tried adding it to the css file only, but that didn't work, either):

   ```
   <style>
   #displaybox {
   z-index: 10000;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*older IE*/
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
   -moz-opacity: .50; /*older Mozilla*/
   -khtml-opacity: 0.5;   /*older Safari*/
   opacity: 0.5;   /*supported by current Mozivalidate-textlla, Safari, and Opera*/
   background-color:#000000;
   position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;
   }
   </style>
   ```

8)  I copied and pasted just these two lines from the source file (I don't need the other two buttons) into the index file after `<?php get_header(); ?>`:

```
<div id="displaybox" style="display: none;"></div>
<input type="button" value="View As Image" onClick="javascript:return convert();">
```

9)  I copied and pasted this line from the source file into the index file after the `<div id="captme">`:

```
<canvas id="localcanvas" style="display:none" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

10) All that and nothing works. I can click on the button but it renders nothing.

What went wrong? Thanks for any guidance you share!

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me. It renders picture from div solnePuzzle and post to PHP script via ajax post. In PHP script save.php, I base_64 decode and save content via file_put_content to img.

[html2canvas js](http://solnydizajn.sk/js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js)

```
function capture() {
    $("#solnePuzzle").html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (e) {
            $("#img_val").val(e.toDataURL("image/png"));
            var t = $("#myForm").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: "save.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    box: box,
                    form: t
                },
                success: function (e) {
                    alert(e.text)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response, does this method function and output like http://kpomservices.com/html5canvas/indexsucc.html? Would you mind sharing where you are using your method so I can get a better visual?

Comment: This was actually one of the many methods I did that didn't work. However, I did plug in what you had above. I had the save.php still on my servers and all the js scripts. I clicked on my button in hopes to see what I've been trying to achieve, only to be shown all the code within the save.php file and an unknown broken image after the echo.

Comment: I figured maybe I forgot to add `<?php` tag at the beginning of the file and the `?>` at the end of the file. So I added the two code snippets. Well, after clicking on my button to convert the div to an image, I received the white screen of death. So, I quit. I was really trying to avoid using PicPick to do this, because the fix region feature is movable around the screen when I need it to always stay in an exact position. Looks like I'm stuck with it, though. Ugh! I'm so through it's not even funny. Thanks though for trying to help.

Comment: Do you have any preview?

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached | solnydizajn.sk’s server IP address could not be found."*

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}

.dataset {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;


}

.widget {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;

    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #333;

    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;


    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


    display: inline-block;
    page-break-after: always;

}

.widget .header p {
   padding: 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
   max-width: 360px;
}

.widget .header .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 36px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;

}

.widget .header:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.widget .header  .title.selected {
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    background-color: #EEF;

}

.widget .content {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.autolayout {
    display: inline-block;
}

.element {
    width: 360px;
}

.compact .content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.compact .row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.compact .cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.compact .row.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}



.toolbar {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
}

.toolbar .basis {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.btn {
    /*min-width: 60px;*/
}


.cell.value {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-wrap: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.cell.freq {
    width: 60px;
}

.cell.glyph {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}


.element {

}
.element table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.element td {
    padding: 0px;

}

.element .selectable:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


.element .stat {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-weigth: bold;
    color: darkgray;
}



.element .bar {
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.bar-both {
    background-color: #0a67a3 !important;

}

.bar-fg {
    background-color: #3e97d1 !important;
}

.bar-bg {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
}

.selected .bar-fg {
    background-color: #FC0;
}

.selected .bar-both  {
    background-color:#FA0;
}

tr.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .selectable:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.crosstab tr.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .header p {
    max-width: 600px;
}


.crosstab td {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.crosstab td.value {
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-align: left;
}

.crosstab .cell {
    vertical-align: top;
}



.crosstab th.cell {
    max-width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.crosstab .n {
    color: darkgray;
}
.fieldlist {
}

.constraints {
    min-width:300px;
    padding: 10px;

    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


}
.constraints table {
    width: 100%;

}

.sidenote {
  max-width:300px;
  padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.headnote {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info-block {
    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
    background-color: #eee;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;

    /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9bc0cf, 0 0 0 3px #e0ebf0;*/
}

.menu-item {
}

.menu-item-value {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.gradient-blue {
    background: #b8e1fc; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8e1fc), color-stop(10%, #a9d2f3), color-stop(25%, #90bae4), color-stop(37%, #90bcea), color-stop(50%, #90bff0), color-stop(51%, #6ba8e5), color-stop(83%, #a2daf5), color-stop(100%, #bdf3fd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=0); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

```html
<span id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
    <div class="header ng-scope">
      <div class="title ng-binding">AGE</div>
      <p class="ng-binding">Patient age, in years</p>
    </div>
    <div class="element ng-scope">
      <div ng-show="hasData()" class="content">
        <table ng-model="table" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <colgroup>
            <col/>
            <col width="60x"/>
            <col width="100px"/>
          </colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="cell value">Value</th>
              <th class="cell freq">Freq</th>
              <th class="cell value"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="0" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="0 to 19" class="ng-scope ng-binding">0 to 19</span>
            </td>

            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">17.2%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 17.234468937875754%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="20" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="20 to 39" class="ng-scope ng-binding">20 to 39</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">18.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 18.03607214428858%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="40" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="40 to 59" class="ng-scope ng-binding">40 to 59</span>
            </td>

            <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">34.3%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 34.2685370741483%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="60" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="60 to 79" class="ng-scope ng-binding">60 to 79</span>
            </td>

            <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">24.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 24.04809619238477%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort --><tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="80" class="selectable ng-scope">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="80 to 99" class="ng-scope ng-binding">80 to 99</span>
            </td>

            <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">6.4%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
              <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 6.4128256513026045%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
          <tr ng-show="getShowMean()" class="">
            <td class="stat">Mean</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">46.1</td>
          </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>


    </div>
  <!-- ngRepeat: field in getChildren(field) -->
</span>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>

<div id="img-out"></div>
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in your fiddle

Comment: use jquery cdn           
                                        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>