# Convert a div(contains apex chart + confetti) animations to GIF

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Heyy, I'm having a div which contains apex chart and confetti, when charts completes the animation the confetti will run. Now i want to save this as gif.

When i try solution from online/stackoverflow only confetti is converting as gif(that too if if querselect confetti canvas) , but i want a div(contains apex chart + confetti) to be convert to gif.

Is this possible??

I tried the bellow code

`            startRecording();

```
        function startRecording() {
        const chunks = []; // here we will store our recorded media chunks (Blobs)
        
        const stream = canvas.captureStream(); // grab our canvas MediaStream
        const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream); // init the recorder

        
        rec.ondataavailable = e => {chunks.push(e.data) ; console.log("New data avialbe" , e.data)};
        console.log("Recording started")
        setReAnimate(reAnimate+1)
        // only when the recorder stops, we construct a complete Blob from all the chunks
        rec.onstop = e => exportVid(new Blob(chunks, {type: 'video/webm'}));
        
        rec.start();
        
        setTimeout(()=>{rec.stop();console.log("Recording Stoped")}, 10000); // stop recording in 3s
        }

        function exportVid(blob) {
        const vid = document.createElement('video');
        vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // vid.controls = true;
        // document.body.appendChild(vid);
        // const a = document.createElement('a');
        // a.download = 'myvid.webm';
        // a.href = vid.src;
        console.log("Video link ---", vid.src)
        // a.textContent = 'download the video';
        // document.body.appendChild(a);
        console.log("Video Exported")
        }
```

`

Comment: Search your question's title on StackOverflow. You'll find answers there - do any of them help you? [How do you convert an html div to image and then save as gif or png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590235/how-do-you-convert-an-html-div-to-image-and-then-save-as-gif-or-png)